# Data doesnt appear on txt

Tags: powershell, regedit

im trying to extract the active users of my pc via registry keys,i check HKLM... and HKU... and then i compare them to check for the active users, but when i try to extract the data via out-file -force to remove the previous users saved on the txt`s and i execute the script again, it only gives me one result as if only one user is active.

```
$regLM = "Registry::HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\"
$clav1 = Get-Item "$regLM\S-1-X-Y-*"

# Salida de usus de HKLM
foreach ($usus1 in $clav1.PSChildName) {
    Write-Host "Clave de usu HKLM: $usus1"
    $usus1 | Out-File "C:\InH\InstM\PRUREG1.txt" -Force
    #$usus1 >> "C:\InH\InstM\PRUREG1.txt"
}
Write-Host "Claves de USU de HKLM ^"

$regCU = "Registry::HKEY_USERS\"
$clav2 = Get-Item "$regCU\S-1-X-Y-*"

# Salida de usus de HKUSU
foreach ($usus2 in $clav2.PSChildName) {
    Write-Host "Clave de usu HKU: $usus2"
    $usus2 | Out-File "C:\InH\InstM\PRUREG2.txt" -Force
    #$usus2 >> "C:\InH\InstM\PRUREG2.txt"
}
Write-Host "Claves de USU de HKUSU ^"

$clavesiguales = @{
    ReferenceObject = (Get-Content -Path "C:\InH\InstM\PRUREG1.txt")
    DifferenceObject = (Get-Content -Path "C:\InH\InstM\PRUREG2.txt")
}
$clavlimpias = Compare-Object @clavesiguales -ExcludeDifferent | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
Write-Host "Se sacaron las claves y se guardan en un txt $clavlimpias"
$clavlimpias | Out-File "C:\InH\InstM\USUACTIV.txt" -Force
```

Heres the exit of the code, doesnt get me the keys of the users.
[image]

The commented lines are how it should work but it doesnt delete the data stored on itself everytime it gets executed.

[image]

Comment: Instead of `foreach` loops, try `$clav1.PSChildName | Out-File "C:\InH\InstM\PRUREG1.txt" -Force` and  `$clav2.PSChildName | Out-File "C:\InH\InstM\PRUREG2.txt" -Force`… Then, `Compare-Object @clavesiguales -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual` could give expected results?

Comment: @JosefZ spot on working as i expected ty